# Can't run unit tests for KnowRob

Tags: knowrob

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to do so according to the [documentation](http://knowrob.org/doc/plunit_testing). For example:

```
rosrun rosprolog rosprolog-test comp_temporal

Warning: /home/al/catkin_ws/src/stacks/knowrob/knowrob_common/prolog/rdfs_computable.pl:546:
    Singleton variable in branch: OneOfList
ERROR: /home/al/catkin_ws/src/stacks/knowrob/comp_temporal/prolog/comp_temporal.plt:21:
    plunit:begin_tests/4: Undefined procedure: plunit:'$declare_module'/5
Warning: /home/al/catkin_ws/src/stacks/knowrob/comp_temporal/prolog/comp_temporal.plt:21:
    Goal (directive) failed: plunit:begin_tests(comp_temporal)
ERROR: /home/al/catkin_ws/src/stacks/knowrob/comp_temporal/prolog/comp_temporal.plt:107:
    PL-Unit: cannot close unit comp_temporal: no open unit
Warning: /home/al/catkin_ws/src/stacks/knowrob/comp_temporal/prolog/comp_temporal.plt:107:
    Goal (directive) failed: plunit_comp_temporal:end_tests(comp_temporal)
ERROR: Prolog initialisation failed:
ERROR: '<meta-call>'/1: Undefined procedure: plunit_comp_temporal:'unit test'/4
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/202504/can%27t-run-unit-tests-for-knowrob/) by [Alexey Reshetnyak](https://answers.ros.org/users/21462/alexey-reshetnyak/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17 on 2015-02-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've just tested on Indigo/Trusty and got the same error. In the SWI Prolog version that comes with trusty, the 'plunit' unit testing library is installed by default, which has not been the case in Precise. We therefore still have a copy of plunit in the knowrob_common package. As a workaround, you can try to delete the file `knowrob/knowrob_common/prolog/plunit.pl`. I'll have a look at this later and try to find a cleaner solution.

---

Originally posted by [moritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/214/moritz/) with karma: 2673 on 2015-02-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Alexey Reshetnyak](https://answers.ros.org/users/21462/alexey-reshetnyak/) on 2015-02-05**:
Thank you! It works.